# Let $X$ be an infinite set. Prove $\exists f : X \rightarrow X$ s.t $\forall x \in X, \forall n > 0, f^n(x)\neq x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading ["Sets, Models and Proofs" by I. Moerdijk and J. van Oosten](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/setsproofs09.pdf) to have some basic understanding of set theory.

There's an exercise I don't see how to work it out:

**Exercise 20** Let $X$ be an infinite set. Prove that there is a bijection $f : X \rightarrow X$ with the property that for every $x \in X$ and all $n > 0$, $f^n(x)\neq x$ [Hint: consider $\mathbb{Z} \times X$, or use Zorn directly].

How to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fix a bijection between $X$ and $X×\mathbb{Z}$"

$\mathbb{Z}$ has the smallest cardinal number among infinite sets.
For any infinite set $X$, we have the cardinal number of $X\times\mathbb{Z}$ the same as $X$. (Direct result from some theorem I don't remember well.) There exists a bijection $g$ between $X$ and $X×\mathbb{Z}$ since the two infinite set have the same cardinal number.

$∃f:Z→Z s. t. ∀x∈Z,∀n>0,fn(x)≠x $ -- just let $f(x)=x+1$.

Apply $f$ on the second element of the pair $(X,\mathbb{Z})\in X\times\mathbb{Z}$

$g\circ f\circ g^{-1}$ is a bijection for $X$ satisfies the condition

since

$(g\circ f\circ g^{-1})^n=g\circ f^{(n)}\circ g^{-1}$

---

Addition on 27th April 2014

On the proof that $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times X$ have the same cardinal number

Or on the construction of bijection between $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times X$

First of all, we construct a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times X^+$ to $X^+$

$f:\mathbb{Z}^+\times X^+\rightarrow X^+$

For each pair $(m\in\mathbb{Z}^+,n\in  X^+)$

We assume

1. $X^+$ is always a set of numbers, if it is not a set of numbers, we can always replace it with a set of numbers having the same cardinal number.
2. n as a number is always in decimal representation, where $[n]\geq 0$ is the floor of $n\geq 0$, namely the largest integer no larger than n with $1\geq n-[n]\geq 0$.

$f((m\in\mathbb{Z}^+,n\in  X^+))= \frac{(m+[n])(m+[n]+1)}{2}+n$

Then we construct a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times X$ to $X$

$g:\mathbb{Z}^+\times X\rightarrow X$

$g((m\in\mathbb{Z}^+,n\in X))=f(m\in\mathbb{Z}^+,n\in X^+)$ if $n\geq 0$

$g((m\in\mathbb{Z}^+,n\in X))=-f(m\in\mathbb{Z}^+,|n|\in X^+)$ if $n\leq 0$

Then we construct a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}\times X$ to $X$

First of all we construct a bijection $h:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$

$h(x\in \mathbb{Z})=2x$ if $x>0$

$h(x\in \mathbb{Z})=2|x|+1$ if $x\leq 0$

Finally

$g((h(m\in\mathbb{Z}),n\in X))$

is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}\times X$ to $X$

---

Clarifications on "replace the infinite set with a set of numbers"

I intended to say "replace the infinite set with a set of real numbers with the same cardinal number"

This is not rigourous statement in mathematics.

Here I replace it with a rigourous one.

If the axiom of choice holds, then a set is infinite if and only if it includes a countable infinite subset.

Set of integer is a countable infinite set. And countable infinite set has the smallest cardinal number among all the infinite set.

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and let $A=X\cup\mathbb{Z}$, then $A$ has the same cardinal number as $X$

This is easy to prove by establishing a bijection between $X$ and $A$.

For any infinite set $X$, let $x\in X$

We have $\{x\}\cup \mathbb{Z}$ is countable infinite and has the same cardinal number as $\mathbb{Z}$. We denote $\{x\}\cup \mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}_x$

$\mathbb{Z}\times X=\bigcup\mathbb{Z}\times x|\forall x\in X$

There exists a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}\times x$ and $\mathbb{Z}_x$ for $\forall x\in X$, since both sets are countable infinite.

There exists a bijection between $\bigcup\mathbb{Z}\times x|\forall x\in X$ and $\bigcup\mathbb{Z}_x|\forall x\in X$

since $\bigcup\mathbb{Z}_x|\forall x\in X=X\cup\mathbb{Z}$

then there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}\times X$ and $X$.

Proved.

Comment: brilliant! ah this is why $X\times \mathbb{Z}$ is hinted!

Comment: What is a "set of numbers"? What are numbers? Do you mean natural numbers? If that is so, what if $X=\mathcal{P(P(P(P(\Bbb N))))}$, can you still replace $X$ by a set of numbers?

Comment: The fact that you can replace a subset of $X$ by a set of integers is fine (we do have to assume some fragment of the axiom of choice for the result in question anyway, and certainly for the hint). But that doesn't mean that you can replace $X$ itself.

Comment: Of course that doesn't mean that I can replace $X$ itself. Instead, I replace $\forall x \in X$ with $\mathbb{Z}_x=\mathbb{Z}\cup x$. And the result is that $\bigcup \mathbb{Z}_x | \forall x\in X=X\cup \mathbb{Z}$ having the same cardinal number as $X$.

Comment: So in order to prove that $\Bbb Z\times X$ and $X$ have the same cardinality, you claim that you can replace each $x$ by $\Bbb Z\times\{x\}$, and then $\bigcup_{x\in X}\Bbb Z\times\{x\}=\Bbb Z\times X$, so the cardinality is the same? That's circular. There's no justification for replacing *all* the points uniformly without enlarging the set.

Comment: You are absolutely right, can you help me with this circular problem?

Comment: Find the answer in the book Set Theory by Thomas Jech, post edited so other's would know.

Comment: I am also reading this book. Anyone an idea if there are somewhere solutions of the exercises of this book? Would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

First prove that for $\Bbb Z$. Which is quite easy.

Then note that if we can show this property for $Y$, then whenever $|X|=|Y|$ we can show this property for $X$ as well. Finally, fix a bijection between $X$ and $X\times\Bbb Z$, and apply the function from the first step on the $\Bbb Z$-coordinates.

Comment: I'm not sure what does it mean to "fix a bijection between $X$ and $X \times \mathbb{Z}$. I tried with Zorn's lemma below. Is it right? ....

Comment: athos: I don't quite understand your proof. When I said that you "fix a bijection", I mean that you [show such bijection exists and] denote by $g$ such bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Following Asaf's hint. Let me have a try.

First, $\exists f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ s. t. $\forall x\in \mathbb{Z},\forall n>0, f^n(x)\ne x$ -- just let $f(x)=x+1$.

Second, a poset $P: (X, f, \le)$ can be defined as bijection $f:U\rightarrow U$, $U\subset X$, $(\forall n>0)(\forall x\in X)(f^n(x) \ne x)$, and $(U, f)\le(V,g)$ iff $U\subset V$ and $u$ is the restriction of $v$ to $U$.

$P$ is not empty due to the first step.

Also, if $\{(U_i, f_i) \mid i\in I \}$ is a chain in $P$, there is a well-defined function $f:\cup_i U_i \rightarrow \cup_i U_i$ is a bijection. So any chain in $P$ has an upper bound.

Now due to Zorn's lemma, such $P$ has a maximal element $(U, f)$.

Third, if $U \ne X$, it shall be either $X-U$ is infinite or finite.

i) if $X-U$ is finite, a bijection $g:X\rightarrow U$ can be defined, then as $X\xrightarrow{g}U\xrightarrow{f}U\xrightarrow{g^{-1}}X$, $h:= g^{-1}\circ f\circ g : X\rightarrow X$ is a bijection that $h^n(x) \ne x$. we are done.

ii) if $X-U$ is infinite, a bijection $Y:V\rightarrow V$ can be found similiarly on $V\subset X-U$, then $h:=f+g$ could be defined, this conflicts with the second step that $(U,f)$ is the maximal element on $P$.

so we are done.